# The thread of my point broke while being screwed-in. How to get the insert out of the shaft?

Tags: arrows

Something curious happened this weekend. One of my field-tips broke inside the shaft. The actual point and the thread of the tip got separated. The problem is that the thread is stilled screwed in the insert and I have a hit insert which means there is everything *inside* of the shaft (nothing to grab). Commonly I would heat the shaft and pull the insert out with a screwed in tip. The broken thread blocks the point of being screwed in of course.

Is there an easy way to get the insert out of the shaft?

Comment: You might want to add what the arrow is made out of, and if the field tip was glued of not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need is a screw extractor.

Usually they are sold with reverse threaded drill bits. You drill into the screw that is recessed and then stick an object in that hole like a flat bladed screwdriver or something of that effect and unscrew the stud.

The trick will be finding a drill bit smaller than the shaft of the stud so you don't damage the threads. You use a left hand or reverse drill bit so there is no chance of driving the stud farther in by the vibration of drilling. Of course this may be more work than the part is worth.

Another option maybe cutting a notch in the end of the stud if a little bit is sticking out but not enough to grab with pliers. Then you could just use a small flat bladed screwdriver to unthread it.

The reason why it broke is probably it was over tightened or bent and straightened.

Comment: In principle this seems like a good idea, and it is for most metal applications, but I wonder if the stresses involved would tend to damage the arrow shaft, bending it or otherwise making it no longer a dependable projectile.

Comment: @JamesJenkins I've done it with various materials the key for a shaft would be to lighty clamp it and drill without forcing the bit.